# How to add attributes in select tag in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am stucking with that, how to add attributes in select tag. I have tried to insert this by jquery but it dosen't worked. data-actions-box="true" this is the bootstrap-select attribute. I have written form field -

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->dropdownList($items ['prompt' => 'Select name', 'data-actions-box' => 'true', 'data-live-search' => 'true', 'title' => 'Select Trainer(s)'])?>
```

It has created select tag with attributes which i wanted -

```
<select id="selectpicker" name="name[]" multiple data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true" title="Select Trainer(s)">
<option value="10">PHP</option>
<option value="11">CSS</option>
<option value="12">HTML</option>
<option value="13">CSS 3</option>
<option value="14">Bootstrap</option>
<option value="15">JavaScript</option>
```

But the problem is, data-action-box is not working. It should have to display select All and deselect All buttons in dropdown list as in image. How to fix this? Please help...

[image]

Comment: where is your code

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam, I have edited my description. Please check.

Comment: first thing is you want to have select and deselect buttons which means you need to have multiselect rather than simple dropdown, you should look into select2 multiselect plugin which does this for you without much effort

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam ok I'll check it. Thanks for the help.